# case in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, case, procedure

Is the usage of `CASE` wrong in the code below?
I am getting an error:

> "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>
> case The symbol "case" was substituted for ";" to continue. "

Code is :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MIK_3PL_ITEM_ERRORS_PROC_1 IS 
  i_error_code varchar2(5);
  i_desc       varchar2(200);
  CURSOR c_3pl_error IS
    SELECT mie.client_item_id, mie.message_id, 
           mie.error_desc, mis.process_flag
      FROM mik_3pl_item_error_etl mie, 
           dummy_staging mis
     WHERE mie.client_item_id = mis.client_item_id
       AND mie.message_id = mis.message_id;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line ('hello');
  for i in c_3pl_error
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line ('in loop');
    DECLARE
      -- L_relations_exist VARCHAR2(1);
      L_error_message   VARCHAR2(255) := NULL;
      L_return          BOOLEAN       := FALSE;
    BEGIN
      select error_code
        into i_error_code
        from mik_3pl_error_desc
       where description = i.error_desc;
      -- dbms_output.put_line(i_error_code);  
      CASE i_error_code
         WHEN  'E2'  THEN dbms_output.put_line ('in case');
      END;  -- end of CASE */
    END; /*End of begin */
  end loop;
END MIK_3PL_ITEM_ERRORS_PROC_1;
```

Comment: You should end `case` statement with `end case;` not just `end;` alone.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntactic error.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be:

```
    ...
      CASE i_error_code
         WHEN  'E2'  THEN dbms_output.put_line ('in case');
      END CASE;  -- end of CASE */
    END;
```

It's trying to treat the `END;` as the end of the block - matching that `END` with the `BEGIN` - and it knows the `case` is still open.

The [documentation for the `CASE` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/case_statement.htm) shows that. (Not to be confused with a [`CASE` expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS278), which does just have `END`. Ahem. Thank you Nicholas!)

Comment: aah ! syntactic error indeed! my bad. Thanks Alex and Nicholas